# Understanding the drupal tables

Tags: drupal

I am reviewing a old system that another developer did with Drupal but i do not understand very well this problem:

There is a node table.
There is another table which it's field_data_field_worker.

field_data_field_worker has a entity_id which makes the relation between node table and field_data_field_worker, that's ok.

There is a node table.
There is another table which it's field_data_field_vacations

field_data_field_vacations has a entity_id which makes the relation between node table and field_data_field_vacations, that's ok.

The problem is that... how i can know this:

When i go to the worker detail, it shows the vacations belong to that worker... but how does Drupal make the relation between the worker and the vacation? because i just see that the unique relation it's node with worker and node with vacation but how Drupal realates worker with vacation? it's not with the node table because... the nodes belong to worker are not same nodes belong to vacation.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Drupal's database structure is fairly complex so you should make custom queries only if you really need to do that. In all other cases do it "drupalish" way.

Use `node_load()` function to get whole node object, `node_save()` (or alternative for D8) to save the node.

For querying multiple nodes use `views` module.

Point is - you don't have to understand Drupal's database structure - it's under the hood. Use the tools Drupal provides to work with database.